# How to update mysql database from C# so that backslash("\") is not escaped?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I have a database as in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fc3ed/1 ,I create an XML from C# code  and call a webapi based off the XML and insert into mysql database as below,am trying to find a simpler way  while inserting into database without disturbing the API call?are there any simpler ways to do this C#?

```
  public void InsertPostCommitTagDetails(XMLSiInfo siInfo)
        {
            bool success = true;
            using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection())
            {
                conn.ConnectionString = AciDev.aciDevConnectionString; // BIT DB
                conn.Open();
                MySqlTransaction myTrans = conn.BeginTransaction();

                qlasrWebApiResponse = PostQlasrWebApiCallsiInfo.xml); //call API using XML

                string sqlInsert = @"INSERT INTO postcommit_tag_details (software_image_build_id, tag_name, xml) VALUES
                                   ('" VALUES ('" + siInfo.siBuildId + "', '" + siInfo.tagName + "',  '" + siInfo.xml + "')";
         }
```

Comment: Your code is unclear. What is supposed to do the line _qlasrWebApiResponce  = PostQlasrWebApiCallsiInfo.xml);_ this is not correct C# syntax. Finally the query in unclear but surely that query needs parameters

Comment: @Steve -which query you are referring to ? software_image_build_id is autoincrement if thats what you are referring to

Comment: ask is simple,I want to match the `Location` tag in XML and replace `\` with '\\'